# Banner slider effect - CardView animation effect to recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, slider, carousel, android-animation

I want to create and implement this effect on my recycler view card effect. I have searched a lot on Google but no success.

If anyone know how to create this card view and implement this animation effect to the card.

[image: Image Swipe Card effect]

Answer (score 0):

This is a `ViewPager2` implementation. If you implement the `viewpager2`, then you have access to positions and their views. Now apply this logic to it, if position = -1, rotate it -30 and if .... One can simplify this logic in one line code: `page.setRotation(30 * position);` (`position =-1 .. 0 .. 1` so `rotation = -30 .. 0 .. 30`)

I haven't tested it but it should work: ( I assume that you are familiar with viewpager2 in java. for kotlin [see this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cube-in-scaling-animation-with-viewpager-in-android/). For a simple example in java [see this post](https://medium.com/swlh/android-infinite-auto-image-slider-using-view-pager-2-android-studio-java-a0e450dec071).)

```
ViewPager2 vp = findViewById(R.id.vpId); // then set its Adapter

vp.setPageTransformer(new ViewPager2.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
         
            page.setRotation(12 * position); // 12 degree is better

            page.setScaleX((float) (1 - 0.9 * Math.abs(position))); //scale down in X
            page.setScaleY((float) (1 - 0.9 * Math.abs(position))); //scale down in Y

        });
```

Comment: I am using JAVA not Kotlin, Also transition i am looking as above .gif shown

Comment: Have you read my answer? What is the problem?

Comment: Its too complicated and also the link you recommend used kotlin

Comment: How you can implement recyclerview but not viewpager? they are similar. both needs adapter. I don't see what is complicated?! (if you are using java then forget about provided link)

Comment: i have successfully implemented the viewpage2. via this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iA9iqygq11Q and i have this output. Now how to tilt the side image 1 and 3?

Comment: yes but too much tild. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SwFKz9hiKqZlnNBYYmU-SSaXXP-ccy8a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have manage to remove some tild but the 3 image is coming above the main image. I want under the main image. Red should come like the green one https://imgur.com/a/klhFmIs

Comment: Ok. What you have shown in your post, it is a little scaled down the side pages. so in my post add also `page.setScaleX(0.9f);` and  `page.setScaleY(0.9f);` Also `30` degree is a little bad angle. set it for example to 20.

Comment: I forget to say that scale just for positions other that 0 (middle). you can exclude 0 case using if-condition.

Comment: I have tried the above answer but its doesn't work. so i try this Float r = 1 - Math.abs(position);
                page.setScaleY(0.85f + r * 0.15f);
                page.setRotation(8 * position);  and this is output imgur.com/a/klhFmIs but Red should come like the green one.

Comment: The final and last thing that I know is the elevation property. elevate middle page a little. again try this: `page.setElevation((float) (10 - 10 * poition));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255458/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-sehrawat-and-c-f-g).